# Can I make this faster - SELECT min(date_time) FROM db.event - to use in a bash script

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to shorten the time it takes to query this table. This is one of our production tables so we cannot do any changes to it.
I'm using the following query on a bash script

```
SELECT min(date_time) FROM db.event
```

But, this is taking about 20min. We have a lot of data on these partitions - around 100GB.
The bash scripts needs to gather the oldest record in this table. Is there any better way to make it more efficient say 10min or less?

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: event
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `event` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `application` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `cdr_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `date_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`date_time`),
  KEY `ix_cdr` (`cdr_id`),
  KEY `ix_type_app_cdr` (`type`,`application`,`cdr_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2985903027 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY LIST (to_days(date_time))
(PARTITION p735660 VALUES IN (735060) ENGINE = InnoDB,
...
... many partitions here
...
...
 PARTITION p735660 VALUES IN (735566) ENGINE = InnoDB)
```

Answer (score 5):

You want to create an index on `date_time`:

```
create index event_datetime on event(date_time)
```

The field `date_time` has to be the first column in the index.

EDIT:

If you can't make changes to the table, then you have a problem.  If the `datetime` is correlated with the `id`, then you could do:

```
select datetime
from event
order by id
limit 1;
```

But this is a big assumption that the minimum date is on the minimum id.

Comment: I cant make changes to the table.

Comment: If you are unable to add an index to the table, then you are out of luck.  Without an index, MySQL must fetch every single row from the table to find which one has the lowest value for `date_time`.